# Python modules not installing correctly mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I am relatively new to python and I was planning to use a module for iTunes in python, specifically this one https://github.com/robertf224/pyTunes and it shows that it has installed, but whenever i try to import the library into python, it shows no module is found. [this is a picture of the errors and terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SahRA.png)

**EDIT:** 
Ok, so i have followed your instructions and it still does not seem to work.
so this is the terminal:

> Jeremys-iMac:~ Jeremy$ sudo pip3 install tunes Password:
>
> The directory '/Users/Jeremy/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent
>   directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been
>   disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
>   executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. The directory
>   '/Users/Jeremy/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not
>   owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check
>   the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with
>   sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. Collecting tunes   Downloading
>   tunes-1.0.tar.gz Installing collected packages: tunes   Running
>   setup.py install for tunes ... done Successfully installed tunes-1.0
>   Jeremys-iMac:~ Jeremy$  Jeremys-iMac:~ Jeremy$ sudo python3 -m pip
>   install tunes The directory '/Users/Jeremy/Library/Caches/pip/http' or
>   its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache
>   has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that
>   directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   The directory '/Users/Jeremy/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent
>   directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been
>   disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
>   executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. Requirement
>   already satisfied: tunes in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages

and this is the python idle:

```
import tunes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tunes
ImportError: No module named 'tunes'
>>> import pytunes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pytunes
ImportError: No module named 'pytunes'
>>> import pyTunes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyTunes
ImportError: No module named 'pyTunes'
>>> import tunes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import tunes
ImportError: No module named 'tunes'
>>> import tunes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import tunes
ImportError: No module named 'tunes'
>>>
```

Comment: You used `pip` to install, which installs to Python 2.7, and then tried to import in Python 3. You want to install with `pip3` to install in your Python 3 install. Also, never post pictures of text; post the text in your question. Search engines can't index the text in your picture, and a lot of question readers will skip your question rather than load the picture to figure it out.

Comment: next time, please post code and logs as text instead of as an image.

Comment: ok, thank you for your advice, i will try to keep it in mind the next time i ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

You've installed the module under python 2.7, but you're trying to import it in python 3.5

So you would need to either import it from python 2.7 or use the pip corresponding to the python that (idle?) uses